# I have a table on the Lua stack. How can I push a function on the stack that returns this table?

Tags: lua

Using the `C` API, I have pushed a table on the **Lua** stack. How can I push a function on the stack that returns this table?

The closest I can find is `lua_pushcclosure`, but that pushes a `lua_CFunction` on the stack, not a real **Lua** function, and that is not acceptable in my case because I want to use `setfenv` later, which only works with real **Lua** functions.

Regards

Comment: I think you may have to use `dostring` for this and pass the table as an argument to a function that returns the closure/function you want.

Comment: thanks, but dumping the table as text is something that I already thought about, and I am looking for a faster cleaner solution

Comment: I never said anything about dumping a table as text. The table on the stack is fine. You just use `dostring` to get a function on the stack that can create a lua function that closes over the table passed as argument to the outer function. `function(tab) return function() return tab end end`.

Comment: That would we `luaL_dostring` and `local tab = ...; return function() return tab end`.

Comment: ... but using `setfenv` on that function wouldn't achieve anything since it doesn't access its environment.

Comment: Etan, big thanks! This appears to work:
         status = luaL_dostring(L_Old, "return function (ppp) return function () return ppp end end");
         if (!status) {
      // push table here
         status = lua_pcall(L_Old, 1, LUA_MULTRET, 0);
         }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old question, but I now add the correct answer as suggested by Etan.

```
status = luaL_dostring(L, "return function (ppp) return function () return ppp end end");
if (!status) {
    // push table here
    status = lua_pcall(L, 1, LUA_MULTRET, 0);
}
```

Regarding the question making no sense, I am aware that setfenv has no effect.

*My only requirement was that setfenv can be executed without causing a crash.*

Answer (score 0):

Well, you do the obvious. Since it must be a "real Lua function", you must create a real Lua function that returns the table.

Something like this:

```
local tbl = ...
return function() return tbl end
```

This is a Lua chunk that, when executed, will return a function that returns the first parameter the original chunk was called with.

So simply use `luaL_loadstring` to load that string. Call the resulting chuck with your table; the return value will be the function you desire.

That being said, your question ultimately makes no sense. `setfenv` will not accomplish anything of value here. Setting the environment of a function that returns a local table will not affect anything stored *within* that table.